# verify data switch is set to No - Capybara

Tags: capybara

I have the following html.

```
<div class="toggle_checkbox switchLogin aligned" data-section="secure_content" data-switch="no">
```

When I browse to the page I wish to test that the data switch is set to no.I have tried something like this:

```
result = page.find('.toggle_checkbox switchLogin aligned').data-switch
assert result == 'no'
```

But this does not work. Anybody have any idea how I can verify this using capybara?

Thanks!

Comment: what does `result` equal? should it be `assert result == 'no'`

Comment: hi danmanstx - yes, thats correct. My bad, it was a typo in the original posting, I have updated the posting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
result = page.find('.toggle_checkbox.switchLogin.aligned')['data-switch']
assert result == 'no'
```

A couple things to note.

When locating an element using multiple classes (ie the class attribute has multiple words separated by spaces), the css-selector needs to put a period in front of each.

The css-selector:

```
.toggle_checkbox switchLogin aligned
```

Actually means find an element with class "toggle_checkbox", within that find an element of type "switchLogin" and then within that an element of type "aligned".

What you actually want is:

```
.toggle_checkbox.switchLogin.aligned
```

Which means to find an element with class "toggle_checkbox", "switchLogin" and "aligned".

Secondly, to get an attribute value of an element, it is done using the `[]` method. The contents of the `[]` is a string matching the attribute name. So the format is basically:

```
element['attribute_name']
```

In your case, it is:

```
element['data-switch']
```

(where element is the found element)

Comment: Perfect, thanks Justin!!! And thanks also for taking the time to post a detailed explanation, this will be a big help to me in the future, much appreciated!